# Lighting doesn't work properly in WebGL build only at one place

Tags: unity, 2d, lighting, webgl, web

So I have a 2d game where a player walks around the level (top view) with a flashlight in front of him. Everything works fine in the editor, however whenever I build it for WebGL and test it in my browser, one room only one, has a problem with lighting, and as I walk in different parts of the room lighting changes in a weird way, and the floor is blinking in the first half of the room, as well as the flashlight is barely visible (if at all).

Here's how it looks in the editor and is supposed to look like:
[image]

And here's a few screenshots from the web build:
[image]

[image]

P.S. Everything works fine in a standalone build.

Also there seems to be no problem when I disable the 4 lights (the whole room works fine), these are the lights (the ones that look like from a window):
[image]

Comment: I would take a look at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1165517/lighting-issues-in-webgl.html. The lighting could be being throttled by the fact that it's WebGL. Try changing the quality settings and maxing Pixel Light Count and anything related to lighting or shadows. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html